Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: this and base files have different roots:
I am trying to use flutter to build an app and when I use flutter build apk --debug, the terminal shows an error.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: this and base files have different roots: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\awesome_notifications_core-0.9.3\android\src\main\kotlin\me\carda\awesome_notifications_core\awesome_notifications_core\AwesomeNotificationsCorePlugin.kt and E:\Flutter\Demo\friend_app\android.

After that, the terminal shows a final conclusion
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':awesome_notifications_core:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

The error shows that it's a path error because of the additional message.
exception: error: source file or directory not found: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\awesome_notifications_core-0.9.3\android\src\main\kotlin\me\carda\awesome_notifications_core\awesome_notifications_core\AwesomeNotificationsCorePlugin.kt
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8e338f1773bfc3bfee65046dd4e56b31\transformed\jetified-flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7769cf7e8b5bce02c68744cecfd66f63\transformed\fragment-1.7.1-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2b2bae35758b02ca643dbaaf6c1420f1\transformed\jetified-activity-1.8.1-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d01dd26609fd4206da9512ca19858a78\transformed\loader-1.0.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\517a6789ad7d5301508d5303f4fcbb53\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx-2.7.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\446c0dc67115b3dc21cd93bd2350d9f5\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-2.7.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\82a49172fb037655d88f3c29636b43fb\transformed\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1df79986bcc44b6ab84e383fc7fe2fce\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.7.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\46682fc2f6cf30df0987556997c818f7\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.7.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\883e6283d77dbfe04fd4dd3538353b9d\transformed\jetified-core-ktx-1.13.1-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\46688848d1792b1443d96f80b822da65\transformed\viewpager-1.0.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9393e3f895eda7cae9f8d7edf60511c2\transformed\customview-1.0.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\89eafab2d88abe6f84f2cd99beb4e4a9\transformed\core-1.13.1-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\207d808f9a3e0ecd72c1081829494456\transformed\lifecycle-runtime-2.7.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0c82131b96664793d073578bca5501c7\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-process-2.7.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common-java8\2.7.0\2ad14aed781c4a73ed4dbb421966d408a0a06686\lifecycle-common-java8-2.7.0.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.7.0\85334205d65cca70ed0109c3acbd29e22a2d9cb1\lifecycle-common-2.7.0.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a887485df84a15566ef956e91d62fa38\transformed\jetified-window-1.2.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c892d4107035f039f683388c44d2eafe\transformed\jetified-window-java-1.2.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7d66cd44e7db9fd28733adf025a25753\transformed\jetified-annotation-experimental-1.4.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7010d98a87f3d242017e5661cc165477\transformed\jetified-savedstate-1.2.1-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2874dd06e81b08bda409fc819a562643\transformed\core-runtime-2.2.0-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.arch.core\core-common\2.2.0\5e1b8b81dfd5f52c56a8d53b18ca759c19a301f3\core-common-2.2.0.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c18d4bf55f6dd8690e719fccd19b9fa8\transformed\versionedparcelable-1.1.1-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.collection\collection\1.1.0\1f27220b47669781457de0d600849a5de0e89909\collection-1.1.0.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d9e07c900551e2ecdff7adf83fa6712e\transformed\jetified-annotation-jvm-1.8.0.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e1062a7a59375381d8ce18cf65e7133d\transformed\jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.1.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\82ea9e5a4bafcd97d0085ad546121155\transformed\jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9268794d3a751e33b5d7dcb408935b40\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.8.20.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2f23869e4566f2a47119b93ca1584b63\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.8.20.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\413b8b924e44c47201519cf8c1765b78\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\83f069aa3a123ab03debf9a90d551a09\transformed\jetified-annotations-23.0.0.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c9a1658a9f50442630fa5a02c470a80c\transformed\jetified-startup-runtime-1.1.1-api.jar
exception: warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Users\u6C88u5146u5947\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\049d039430f9acc22ce6536f81435c02\transformed\jetified-tracing-1.2.0-api.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What can I do to solve the problem?
